# Concurrency with NS Fetched Results Controller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have used core data before, however I have just adopted a new core sata stack using NSPersistentContainer and am tackling a new issue.

Setup: So I have a tableview which loads data via the NSFetchedResultsController.  Each row has 2 textfields.  My goal is to save user data entered into those 2 textfields as the user is typing.  Whenever the value in a textfield is changed i also need it to update NSFetchedResultsController’s delegate, because i have calculation functions in FRC’s delegate, which compute the numbers the user types in the two textfields.

The issue is that whenever i update the core data object modified by the textfieldDidChange action it cancels editing because i believe the main thread is being blocked by the core data write.

FRC Code

```
  let context = coreDataController.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NumbersMO>(entityName: "Numbers")
    // Configure the request's entity, and optionally its predicate

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    Controller.delegate = self
```

TextFieldDidChange Code

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
    let number = Double(sender.text)

    let object = controller(object at: indexPath)

    object.value1 = number // This freezes main thread and causes editing to stop

    }
```

The goal is to have user data instantly saved as the user types it while also notifying FRC’s delegate of the change, so as to update my calculations without blocking the main thread.

Has anyone tackled this before?

Edit: working on format, am stuck on mobile right now

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: @shallowThought Relevant code added

Comment: Please can you show the code for the FRC delegate didChangeObject method - I suspect it is reloading the cell in response to the object being updated, and this is causing the textField to be removed from the view hierarchy, which is somehow locking.  Also, what are the calculations the FRC delegate methods are used for?